# How to solve the package installing problem in RStudio?

Tags: r, package, install.packages

I have been trying to install `ggfortify` package in my RStudio.
So, I have used the following codes as this is not a built-in package-

```
if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("sinhrks/ggfortify")

install.packages ("ggfortify")
library(ggfortify)
```

Since then I could not be able to install any packages in my RStudio. What should I do now.

The followings are the error messages I got while installing the `ggplot2` package:

```
require("ggplot2")
```

error messages -

```
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], 
c(lib.loc,.libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
namespace ‘pillar’ 1.4.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.4.3 is required
```

How can I fix this? should I uninstall and reinstall R studio?

Comment: You should update the pillar package. Or even better, all installed packages.

Comment: @Roland
Thanks. I have another query to you....do I have to install the updates everytime, whenever I want to use that `ggfortify` package?

Comment: @ShakilAhmedShaon No you do not need to update every time.  When you install the package it puts a copy on your local machine.  However, when you update one package you may need to update others because packages borrow (depend on) functions from each other.  If one package needs an updated version you will run into the issue you saw.